# Printf with AWK in Fortran D-like format "0.xxxxxD+x"

Tags: shell, awk, sed, fortran, csh

## Context

In Fortran programming language, there is a format, the "D" format, when you want to print a float. For instance, the float:

```
1234.56
```

Will be printed as:

```
0.123456D+4
```

Yes, with `D` and this pseudo-scientific notation with floating point.

---

## Question

I would like to reproduce this specific formatting in my shell (wich is csh by the way but we don't care) thanks to AWK and the less "sed" possible.
AWK is not mandatory but I think is a good way to do it (with the "e" format %e at start and some "sed" after)

---

## Where I am

Here is the text I need to read first:

```
NU     0.12345D+4     0.56789D+5
```

which is a typical input/config file (with two floats to read) for a tool in Fortran.

And here is my fully commented code in C-Shell:

```
set var_str_ori = `cat "$file" | awk '{print $2}'` # var_str_ori = "0.12345D+4"

# Transforming into a calculable float
set var_ori = `echo "$var_str_ori" | sed s/D/E/g | awk '{printf "%f", $1}'` # var_ori = 1234.500000

# Do some calculus
set var__new = `echo "$var_ori + 42.3" | \bc -l` # var_new = 1276.800000

# Re-formatting (the tricky part!)
set var_str_new = `echo "$var__new" | awk '{printf "%E", $1}' | awk -F. '{print "0."$1$2}' | awk -F"E+" '{print $1"D+0"$2+1}'` # var_str_new = "0.12768D+4"
```

and write the new `$var_str_new` well formatted to obtain the new file which looks like:

```
NU     0.12768D+4     0.56789D+5
```

---

As you can see, there is a trick with AWK/sed to reformat a true scientific format (`x.xxxxE+x`) into a Fortran D-Format. Okay, that's it! If you have any suggestion... Please remember, I'm in C-Shell, without any "function" definition. It (kind of) pure Shell!

Finally, I know that I could simplify my code but this is not the point (this example is deliberately verbose and not optimized). My real question is how to format in "D Fortran like" format.

Comment: It may be worth noting that you may not need to worry about whether the input for the Fortran tool has a `d` or an `e` indicating exponent: they are handled identically.

Comment: You're right but this is a specific Fortran tool which needs to be fed with `D` exponent.

Comment: Though I completely agree with francescalus (usually, the usual E should work), if you definitely need to have "0.1234D+12" format (with leading zero), it might be useful to write a one-liner Fortran code like `double precision x; read*, x; print "(D15.6)", x; end`, save it to `test.f90`, compile (`gfortran test.f90`), and then use a.out in your shell (e.g., `var=$( echo "1.23" | ./a.out )` in bash, which gives 0.123000D+01). Or simply, we could replace E(+|-)[digits] by D(+|-)[digits] by sed etc later?

Comment: Thank's again and I know that. You're totaly right. But I do not manage the Fortran executable I need to use. And I need to use a csh script for other reasons. Tank you for all your comments, really, but neither you nor me can run against my specific professional environment ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can write functions in `awk`,

this may get you started, it doesn't handle negative exponents but can be easily added as well

```
$ awk 'function tovalue(x) 
         {split(x,xa,"D"); 
          return xa[1]*10^xa[2]} 
       function format(x) 
         {p=length(int(x)); 
          return x/(10^p)"D+"p} 

       {print v2=tovalue($2), v3=tovalue($3), format(v2+11)}' file

1234.5 56789 0.12455D+4
```